# Why can't I replace std::map with std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, unordered-map

This question might be a bit sketchy because I do not have the code available at home, but I know this thing otherwise will bug me the whole weekend.

When I tried to update some code to C++11 I began replacing some `std::map` with `std::unordered_map`. The code only used `std::map::find()` to access a specific element in the map, so I figured the replacement should be easy. The returned iterator was stored in an `auto`-typed variable (`auto res = map.find( x )`, so the typing should check out fine. However when accessing the stored element using `res->second.do_stuff()` I got a compiler error, telling me, that `struct std::pair<char, B> does not have a member second`. Now this really confused me, but unfortunately I did not have time to investigate further.

Maybe this is enough information, so someone can give me a hint on this weird compiler error. Or is my understanding that `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` should have the same interface except for the parts which need an ordering, not correct?

**EDIT**:

As promised here some more analysis on the problem. Most likely this will allow someone to help me out better now. As I guessed from the hints in the comments, this was not really caused by the point where I accessed the elements in the map, but by some other part of the code. The reason I found was, that I used the map within Class X to store pointers to other elements of Class X (a kind of tree structure). However this seems to work for `std::map` but not for `std::unordered_map`. Here is some very simple code that exhibits the problem:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

class Test {
  std::map<uint32_t, Test> m_map1; // Works
  std::unordered_map<uint32_t, Test> m_map; // gives error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
};

int main() {
  return 1;
}
```

`std::map` works `std::unordered_map` does not work. Any Ideas why this is the case, or what can be done to get it to work with a `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: The interface is roughly the same, but you'll need to make sure your key types are hashable rather than merely comparable.

Comment: @ildjarn: The keys are simple char as given in the example, so they should be easily hashable. Also the problem does not appear in the definition of the `std::unordered_map<char, B> map` or at the point where I call `find( x )` on it, but rather at the point where I try to access the iterator (or more precisely the member `second`). That is the part that got me confused.

Comment: Could you produce a minimal example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? `std::unordered_map`: http://ideone.com/P2XUa `std::map`: http://ideone.com/etuCH

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Sorry, I do not have to code available over the weekend. I guess I will have to check back on monday and then explain more detailed what the problem was (most likely I will have a solution then as well).

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: Actually the code I am trying to rework is much more complicated with several dependend typedefs within a template. So probably there is a mistake with one of thoses somewhere, so that the compiler get's confused and only outputs a stupid error message or so... Unfortunately I cannot reproduce an example right now of my head. I tried to modify your code a little to match what I am doing, but I do not get the same error. I guess I will have to let this one go until monday :(.

Comment: May-be you wrote `res.second.do_stuff()` and misread the error?

Comment: The compiler is telling you what is wrong. std::map::find returns an iterator, which needs to be dereferenced to get the pair the iterator points to. However, in your case, the compiler appears to be setting the type of your auto variable res to std::pair instead of std::unordered_map::iterator. To find out if this is the case is to try res.second.do_stuff() instead of res->second.do_stuff(). According to this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find std::unordered_map::find returns iterator or const_iterator, so res SHOULD be std::unordered_map::iterator, but who knows?

Comment: Your code compiles fine on my MSVC 2010.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Yes, it might. I started another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473455/why-do-stl-datastructures-need-fully-defined-types/8475450#8475450). As it seems both lines within the class invoke undefined behavior, so the compiler my do, what you expect, may fail or may produce something different altogether. I will add an answer with the details I learned today when I have more time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess that because std::unordered_map needs to rehash, and therefore copy elements, the types need to be complete, whereas a map, only ever working with pointers to elements, will not exhibit that problem.

The solution here is to have an unordered map to a pointer:

```
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<Test> >.
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Unfortunately I did not have time yet, to write a more detailed explanation myself, so I'll let you have the credit ;-). Another thing to note at this point is, that both lines are invalid. As explained in http://drdobbs.com/184403814 incomplete types are never allowed by STL-Collections, so the code was invalid before, but the compiler never caught this. This probably is one of those cases, where undefined behavior doesn't hurt you usually, but you cannot be sure. At least now we are safe.

Answer (score 12):

Using both `map` and `unordered_map` with incomplete types involves undefined-behavior:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> [...]
>
> — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: from the standard library requirements part of the C++ standard. I think it was there since C++98.

Comment: It could be nice if compilers could generate good error messages and not generate working code in this case (containers of incomplete type). We have no way to ensure that our code will work tomorrow on another compiler/version.

Comment: @Renaud: This is a part of a more general discussion of whether undefined behavior is good or bad. Sometimes you do not care for porting your code to other platforms, but doing something exploiting the knowledge of your implementation is useful. E.g. the useful `struct Tree { std::list<Tree> children; };` works correctly with my toolchain, but will fail if done as you say. Other example is casting pointers to non-PODs whose memory layout I know to be identical, but technically is undefined behavior.