# Why do STL-Datastructures need fully defined types

Tags: c++, stl, undefined-behavior

When looking for a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452566/why-cant-i-replace-stdmap-with-stdunordered-map), I found the this [thread on another forum](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/language-c-moderated/588292-forward-declaration-unordered_map.html), which says that the standard requires all template parameters to STL-Datastructure to be fully defined. This means producing a structure which stores elements of the it's own type within itself invokes undefined behavior. However as far as I can tell this is not caught for most pre-C++11 datastructure (i.e. `std::vector`, `std::map` etc.).

What actually could be the problem of using incomplete types within STL-Datastructures? Or more exactely what potential danger could the following code cause:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <map>

struct Test {
  std::map<uint32_t, Test> m_map1;
};

int main() {
  return 1;
}
```

Or is this one of those issues, where this code might not compile with some STL-Implementations, but if it does compile, you can be sure that it works?

Comment: Mathew Austern provides a good explanation [here](http://drdobbs.com/184403814). It could well be an answer if summarized and linked to the article. Right now I am a bit caught up at work But someone can feel free to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: because the standard says so.  More generally,
depending on the implementation, and what each type and function does,
instantiating a template may require a complete definition.  The authors
of the standard either didn't want to, or didn't have time to analyse
and specify in detail in what cases they didn't want to require complete
definitions, and settled for a blanket statement.  Note too that when
the standard was written, there was relatively little experience with
STL, and one could be sure that there wasn't some clever optimization
which would require an instance of the argument type within a class;
rather than risk banning such an optimization, it seemed safer to
require a complete type.

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem your compiler faces with incomplete types is that it might be unable to fully determine the size of your *struct Test*. And thus, how could some container internally instantiate a *Test*?

Actually, as James said, it depends on how the std::map template uses the second type parameter. As long as it doesn't use instances but *Test* pointers it should compile.
But who can claim this for all STL- (or in general, Container-) implementations out there?
As the STL is part of your compiler suite one *potential danger* is reducing the portability of your code.