# C++ Struct that contains a map of itself

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors

Simple question: How do I get this to work?

```
struct A {
    double whatever; 
    std::unordered_map<std::string, A> mapToMoreA; 
}
```

g++ error: std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second has incomplete type

As far as I understand, when instantiating the map, the compiler needs to know the size of A, but it doesn't know this because the map is declared in A's declaration, so is the only way to get around this to use pointers to A (don't feel like doing that)?

Comment: It isn't very often that an object needs a container with siblings and not pointers. What's the use case?

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Quite the opposite, quite often one would need a container with siblings (say, a tree implementation). Using pointers is just a workaround more often than not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452566/why-cant-i-replace-stdmap-with-stdunordered-map

Comment: @AndreyT: graphs are the most general case, and there you must have pointers.  Recursive objects - e.g. BinaryTree ::== ( optional left: BinaryTree, optional right: BinaryTree ) are common datastructures, conceptually.  But to implement them in a C/C++ world you need pointers. The pointers to left and right may be hidden, not visible to the outside world, but they are there.  I.e recursive and hierarchical data structures are often enough, but not general.

Comment: @Krazy Glew: That's the whole point. A canonical implementation of an arbitrary (not necessary binary) three calls for a container of children (e.g. list of children) being stored in the parent. The "pointer" in this case is hidden inside the container itself. There's no need for a yet another level of indirection: there's no real reason to store pointers in that list instead of children themselves. A tree is a recursive structure and I want to implement that recursion explicitly. And I can do it, unless quirks of specific implementation prevent me from doing that.

Comment: @Krazy Glew: That's how one'd implement an arbitrary tree in C: each node contains a list of its children (not a list of *pointers* to the children). This is what I would like to be able to do in C++ as well. And if some specific list implementation complains about incomplete types, I'll have to resort to pointers as a *workaround*. This workaround is ugly for more reasons than one. For example, it creates the need for two separate allocators: one for tree nodes and one for child list entries. This is just ugly.

Comment: @Krazy Glew: General graphs are not a comparable example, since general graphs are not recursive, have no explicit hierarchy and therefore do not allow for strict ownership semantics between the nodes. Trees are critically different from general graphs in this respect, which is why I talk about the trees specifically.

Comment: @AndreyT: think about it: to implement a recursive data structure in "raw" C++ - without using the STL - one does something like struct TreeNode { TreeNode *left, *right; ...}.  Or how about a hash table, as some map implementations use: struct A { ... ; HashNode* hash_table[HASH_SIZE]; };   If you want to encapsulate that, you need template<typename T> class HashTable { HashNode hash_table[HASH_SIZE]; };.  But if you define HashTable that way, you wll get the message you complain about. To avoid, you must use a PIMPL.  And PIMPLs are slower. C++ usually chooses speed; else write .js

Comment: @Krazy Glew: No, you are missing my point. When you are implementing a binary tree, you *can* do `struct TreeNode { TreeNode *left, *right; }` but you don't have to. Instead, you *can* also do `struct TreeNode { TreeNode (*childen)[2]; }`, i.e. instead of individual pointers to children, you can use a pointer to an array of children themselves. A pointer will be necessary, no argument here. But it is up to you to decide, where you want to introduce that pointer: *either* pointers to individual elements *or* a pointer to a container of elements themselves.

Comment: Note, that regardless of which approach `TreeNode` you choose, it requires only *one* level of indirection. And when you use a standard container to represent children, that is exactly the same as the second approach in my comment above. The container already contains a pointer inside, i.e. the container itself already introduces one level of indirection. No more levels of indirection are necessary. Once you introduced that one level of indirection by using a standard container, you should be able to store the children themselves in that container. Not pointers, but children themselves.

Comment: You say that using pointers in std contained is similar to `struct TreeNode { TreeNode *left, *right; }`? No, that is false and misleading analogy. If, for example, you implement a `TreeNode` with `std::vector` of *pointers* to children inside, that would be analogous to `struct TreeNode { TreeNode *(*childen)[2]; }` (note the extra `*`). It is analogous to storing a *pointer to an array of pointers* in `TreeNode`. It's *two* levels of indirection, instead of one. Two levels are completely unnecessary.

Comment: When you use a std container to store *pointers* to nodes in a tree, you are introducing a completely unnecessary extra level of indirection. That's simply a waste. The proper way to declare a node in an arbitrary tree is `struct TreeNode { std::vector<TreeNode> children; }` or `struct TreeNode { std::list<TreeNode> children; }`. The point is that it should contain nodes themselves, not pointers to nodes. The implementation of the container already provides that necessary one level of indirection. The only reason to use pointers in that case would be a "crappy" implementation of the container.

Comment: @AndreyT: in C/C++, there are going to be pointers anyway. I can design a container that does not APPEAR to have pointers, that APPEARS to support simple recursion - but that basically makes the container a pimpl, a pointer to a struct that actually contains the root information of the data structure. I agree with you that introducing pointers adds an unnecessary CONCEPTUAL level of recursion. Naive programmers may find this confusing.  But, ironically, designing the container so that recursion is not visible to the programmer adds an extra level of indirection to the generated machinne code.

Comment: @AndreyT: BTW, (1) I agree with you that STL containers should document whether they can be simply recursive, i.e. it should be part of their definition, (2) I lean towards making all such containers allow simple recursion.  But (3) I am aware that there is a performance cost, one extra level of indirection for doing so.  And (4) C/C++ usually veer towards performance rather than making things easier for naive programmers.

Comment: @AndreyT: by the way, the reason I am wasting so much time in this conversation is that I distinctly remember my own frustration with C/C++'s lack of support for recursive data structures. I.e. I sympathize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time it will depend on the container implementation details (more precisely, on what gets instantiated at the point of container declaration and what doesn't). Apparently, `std::unordered_map` implementation requires the types to be complete. At the same time GCC's implementation of `std::map` compiles perfectly fine with incomplete type.

To illustrate the source of such difference, consider the following example. Let's say we decided to make our own naive implementation of `std::vector`-like functionality and declared our vector class as follows

```
template <typename T> class my_vector {
  T *begin;
  T *end;
  ...
};
```

As long as our class definition contains only pointers to `T`, the type `T` is not required to be complete for the class definition itself. We can instantiate `my_vector` itself for an incomplete `T` without any problems

```
class X;
my_vector<X> v; // OK
```

The "completeness" of the type would be required *later*, when we begin to use (and therefore instantiate) the individual methods of `my_vector`.

However, if for some reason we decide to include a direct instance of `T` into our vector class, things will chahge

```
template <typename T>
class my_vector {
  T *begin;
  T *end;
  T dummy_element;
  ...
};
```

Now the completeness of `T` will be required very early, at the point of instantiation of `my_vector` itself

```
class X;
my_vector<X> v; // ERROR, incomplete type
```

Something like that must be happening in your case. The definition of `unordered_map` you are dealing with somehow contains a direct instance of `A`. Which is the reason why it is impossible to instantiate (obviously, you would end up with infinitely recursive type in that case).

A better thought through implementation of `unordered_map` would make sure not to include `A` into itself as a direct member. Such implementation would not require `A` to be complete. As you noted yourself, Boost's implementation of `unordered_map` is designed better in this regard.

Comment: Just to add on from other answers: boost::unordered_map also seems to allow incomplete types.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any STL containers other than smart pointers that work with incomplete types. You can use a wrapper struct however if you don't want to use pointers:

```
struct A {
    struct B { double whatever; }; 
    std::unordered_map<std::string, B> mapToB; 
};
```

**Edit:** Here is a pointer alternative if the above doesn't meet your use case.

```
struct A {
    double whatever;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<A>> mapToMoreA; 
};
```

You can also just use `boost::unordered_map` which not only supports incomplete types but also has far greater debug performance in Visual Studio as Microsoft's implementation of `std::unordered_map` is incredibly inefficient due to excessive iterator debugging checks. I am unaware of any performance concerns on gcc for either container.

Comment: But B does not contain the map member.

Comment: This is true, a container that accepts an incomplete type or use of pointers are an alternative.

Comment: @AJG85: You can easily create a container that accepts an incomplete type, via templates such as  template<class BaseContainer> class AcceptsIncomplete { private: BaseContainer* bptr; AcceptsIncomplete() : bptr( new BaseContainer ) {} ... enumerate all of the methods of BaseContainer, delegated through bptr (which is a pain.  I wish there was a way to do non-inheritance based delegation automatically.

Comment: @AJG85: or pointers to the elements: template<typename T> class AcceptsIncomplete : public std::map< shared_ptr<T> > { ... // unfortunately, inheriting from stl types like std::list and std::map is discouraged

Comment: @KrazyGlew Most STL containers use operations which would cause incomplete types to be undefined behavior. However you can create templates which work with incomplete types. Inheriting from STL containers is discouraged due to implementations not having virtual destructors AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/) has a handy utility explicitly for this purpose – [`boost::recusive_wrapper<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/recursive_wrapper.html). The following should work:

```
struct A {
    double whatever; 
    std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::recursive_wrapper<A>> mapToMoreA; 
};
```

<strike>The only notable drawback is that Boost.Variant has not yet been updated to support C++11 move semantics.</strike> Update: added in Boost 1.56.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a pointer to the map. The pointer must be of type void* in this case (can be hidden behind a set of functions). Maybe there are alternatives to std::unordered_map that can cope with incomplete value types.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you usually use pointers, which have predefined constant size, for incomplete types:

This of course changes how you use the map: you'll have to dereference with the `*` or `->` operators to access members and have to `delete` the pointers at some point.

```
struct A
{
    double bla;
    std::map<std::string, A*> mapToMoreA;
};
```

Member functions of A should be split into a prototype inside the `struct` block and implemented later, otherwise A and its members are not yet completely defined:

```
struct A
{
    double bla;
    std::map<std::string, A*> mapToMoreA;
    void doStuff(const std::string& str);
};

void A::doStuff(const std::string& str)
{
    mapToMoreA[str] = new A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If having the map hold pointers isn't acceptable, perhaps this will work for you:

```
struct A {
  struct hidden;
  std::unique_ptr<hidden> pimpl;
};

struct A::hidden {
  double whatever;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, A> mapToMoreA;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can just forward declare `struct A;` prior to its definition and the compiler should be happy.

EDIT:  So after being downvoted several times, I wrote the following to see what I was missing:

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>                                                                                      
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A;

struct A {
    double whatever;
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, A> mapToMoreA;
};

int main(void)
{
    A b;
    b.whatever = 2.5;
    b.mapToMoreA["abc"] = b;
    std::cerr << b.mapToMoreA["abc"].whatever << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine using g++ 4.2.1 on my mac, and prints out "2.5" when it's run (as expected).

Sorry that I don't have `unordered_map` without boost.  Is that the issue?  (i.e., does `std::unordered_map` somehow place more constraints on the compiler than boost does?)  Otherwise, I'm not sure what I'm missing here about the question. Those downvoting this, please enlighten me with comments.  Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't work because it still doesn't give the compiler information on the size of A, just that A exists.

Comment: Well, it just worked for me.  (I just wrote the above code which compiled fine in g++... will edit.)

Comment: @Turix - try deleting your forward declaration. I wager that it will *still* compile. If so, your solution didn't really change anything.

Comment: @Rob You were right. (Although the OP is apparently getting a compiler error for this code.)  However, the larger point is that not only does it compile, it also runs.  The compiler somehow figured out what to do with the "incomplete type" issue that everyone else is posting about.

Comment: I believe (I'm searching for proof) that `boost::unordered_map` allows incomplete types while `std::unordered_map` doesn't.

Comment: See AnderyT's answer - it all depends on the implementation of unordered_map. Just because it works for you doesn't mean the standard *requires* it to work.