# Fetching value from std::map which is a user defined class object leading to invalid read

Tags: c++

For Simplicity I am creating a demo program which simulates the problem.

In below program when I try access map using **worksFineWithPointer** function everything works fine i.e. by store the address of value fetched from map and results are also expected and when I try to access map using **problem** function i.e. store the value in object, it does not shows expected results.

I tried running my faulty function with Valgrind it showed lot of invalid read request. But understanding valgrind is quite difficult for me so didn't got much (if an easy book can be sugested or online reference that would be great too). If I comment out the **problem** function no valgrind errors.

Then I compiled the program with electric fence and it immediately core dumped and I got to know that which line is having a issue which is as below:

```
#10 0x0000000000401721 in Node::operator= (this=0x7ffccb72e720, obj=...) at test.cc:33
#11 0x0000000000401b83 in A::problem (this=0x7ffccb72e7c8, prefix="test") at test.cc:102
#12 0x0000000000401350 in main () at test.cc:114
(gdb) f 11
#11 0x0000000000401b83 in A::problem (this=0x7ffccb72e7c8, prefix="test") at test.cc:102
102                 crawler = crawler.getMap()[ch];
```

Not sure what is wrong in above line it will just call operator= and values should get copied in crawler object. May be I am missing some concept of C++ here.

Below is the full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    private:
        map<char, Node> mymap;
        bool test;

    public:
        Node():test(false){}

        bool getTest()
        {
            return test;
        }

        void setTest()
        {
            test = true;
        }

        map<char, Node>& getMap()
        {
            return mymap;
        }
};

class A {
    private:
        Node* root;

    public:
    A()
    {
        root = new Node();
    }

    void insert(string word)
    {
        Node* crawler = root;
        for (char ch : word)
        {
            if (crawler->getMap().find(ch) == crawler->getMap().end())
                crawler->getMap()[ch] = Node();

            crawler = &crawler->getMap()[ch];
        }
        crawler->setTest();
    }

    // This way if I access no valgring errors everything works fine
    void worksFineWithPointer(string prefix)
    {
        Node* crawler = root;
        cout << "worksFineWithPointer:" << endl;

        for (char ch : prefix)
        {
            crawler = &crawler->getMap()[ch];
            cout << crawler->getTest() << endl;
        }

    }

    // Problematic Function but not able to find why it is wrong
    void problem(string prefix)
    {
        Node crawler = *root;
        cout << "Boolean Attribute changed to true when using objects instead of pointer:" << endl;

        for (char ch : prefix)
        {
            crawler = crawler.getMap()[ch];
            cout << crawler.getTest() << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.insert("test");
    a.problem("test");
    a.worksFineWithPointer("test");

    return 0;
}
```

Output (When Compiled and ran with Efence no output came as it dumped before printing):

```
Boolean Attribute changed to true when using objects instead of pointer:
1 <<<< how this changed to true
1 <<<< how this changed to true
1 <<<< how this changed to true
1 <<<< this was anyway true

WorksFineWithPointer:
0
0
0
1
```

I am missing some basic C++ concept here I guess, it would be great if someone could explain what is the issue with problematic code statement.

Comment: _I am missing some basic C++ concept here_ `Node *crawler = root;` This initializes a pointer (to `Node`) with another pointer (`root`) i.e. it just copies the address stored in `root` to `crawler`. `Node crawler = *root` This makes a copy of the contents of pointer `root` into `crawler`. For this, the copy constructor of `Node` is used which you didn't implement (but the compiler generated one in this case). That's a big difference.

Comment: @Scheff Yes I haven't implemented the copy constructor, so default copy constructor should do a shallow copy...still what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `problem` function, you are making *copies* of the `Node`s and then iterating through them. That's not the same thing as iterating through the pointers.

But the real issue I think is with your class design

```
class Node
{
    private:
        map<char, Node> mymap;
// ...
};
```

At this point, Node is an incomplete type, and so you can't have a map of that type. (From c++17, I believe a `vector` of incomplete types is allowed though). For a `map`, I think it's ill-formed, so even if your code compiles, it has UB, and *why* it crashes is irrelevant.

Anyway, I think you'd be better off having a map of `char` to `Node*`. Then your class looks like this

```
class Node
{
    private:
        map<char, Node*> mymap;
        bool test;
    public:
// ...   
      map<char, Node*>& getMap()
        {
            return mymap;
        }
};
```

And then your functions become

```
  void worksFineWithPointer(string prefix)
    {
        Node* crawler = root;
        cout << "worksFineWithPointer:" << endl;

        for (char ch : prefix)
        {
            crawler = crawler->getMap()[ch];
            cout << crawler->getTest() << endl;
        }

    }
```

and

```
    void problem(string prefix) // no longer
    {
        Node crawler = *root;
        cout << "Works fine with objects too :)" << endl;

        for (char ch : prefix)
        {
            crawler = *crawler.getMap()[ch];
            cout << crawler.getTest() << endl;
        }
    }
```

and they should both work fine.

Even better, make `mymap` a `map<char, std::unique_ptr<Node>>`.

Comment: `map<char,Node*> const&`

Comment: @numzero the map being returned is being modified.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting better class design but it would be great if you could point out why my code was crashing. How I made an invalid read request.

Comment: @mSatyam The `problem` function is wrong by design, it deep-copies (tries at least) the tree many times (also remember that `map[ch]` creates new map entry is there wasn’t one with that key). Pointers are the way to go.

Comment: Like I said, you have an incomplete type. See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/11438969/8372853. At that point, asking why your code crashes is meaningless. Why the code compiles in the first place is more interesting. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502085/8372853

Comment: And cigien is right, incomplete type may not be used with an STL class (except of `std::unique_ptr`, etc.). That’s UB so may cause all sort of problem. Use `map<char, unique_ptr<Node>>`.

Comment: @cigien Thanks...so using an incomplete type with STL is undefined behavior I read in of the posts you shared......Instead if the type is complete can then I use the map as I used in "problem" function.

Comment: Could you please put it in the answer that this way defining map is undefined behavior  just for future purpose and for others who may see the post.

Comment: @cigien ohhh I was not knowing UB means undefined behavior its there already i see thanks for quick help on this.