# Non-template container iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

Let's suppose we have a class `Container` without a template, and the functions `begin()` and `end()`, witch returns a class `Container_iterator`. The `Container` class has a map in it:

```cpp
class Container
{
    Container_iterator begin();
    Container_iterator end();
};
class Container_iterator
{
    Container operator*();
}
```

Now, this code does not compile, so we add the forward declerations of the classes. However, in the code still does not compile, saying that `Container` is a incomplete type. Is there any way to get the code to compile, or is implementing iterators without templates not possible?

Edit: code

```cpp
namespace json
{
    class JSONobj
    {
        void* to_value;
        json_types t;

    public:
        typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, JSONobj> json_obj;


        // iterator class
        class iterator : std::iterator < std::forward_iterator_tag, JSONobj, size_t>
        {
        public:

        private:
            json_array::iterator it_array;
            json_obj::iterator it_obj;
            json_iterator_types t;

        public:
            iterator(JSONobj::json_array::iterator& _it_array);

            // prefix ++ operator
            iterator& operator++();

            // suffix ++ operator
            iterator& operator++(int);


            std::string key();
            // dereferance operator
            reference operator*();
        };

        inline reference front() {}
        inline reference back() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `Container_iterator::operator*()` return a `Container`? Shouldn't it return something like a `Container::value_type&`, possibly `Container::value_type const&`?

Comment: There's a lot of code here that has nothing to do with the issue. Basically, the issue is with the `json_obj` declaration. Try to get rid of everything that is not related to the problem.

Comment: @bitmask in the map, its defined as map<string, JSONobj>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make `Container_iterator` a nested type member of `Container`, and it'll work:

```
class Container
{
  class Container_iterator
  {
     Container operator*();
  };

  Container_iterator begin();
  Container_iterator end();
};
```

Also, it seems odd that an iterator would return a `Container` instead of an element of the `Container`, but the solution above would work in that case as well.

Comment: I read somewhere to not implement iterators as nested classes, but I guess it's the only way :D

Comment: @RuiqiLi I'm not sure why. There seems no reason not to make it a nested type.

Comment: i have change it to a nested class, still std::map thinks Container is a incomplete type

Comment: What `std::map`? Please make a [mre]

Comment: ill put my entire .h file into a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/dJzmhChJ

Comment: No one is going to read that. Or at least, I'm not. Please add all relevant code to the question as text.

Comment: @RuiqiLi Dumping the contents of that pastebin was likely not what cigien had in mind. Anyway, it doesn't help much. Try following the link given to you to learn how to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @bitmask I have already trimmed of most of the irrelevant code

Comment: After doing some testing, it was originally an unordered_map. Now I changed it to a normal map, so it compiles. can someone explain why unordered_map doesn't work?

Comment: @RuiqiLi https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487164/430766

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get the code to compile

Simply declare the classes before using the declaration. And add the missing semicolon.

Defining the iterator as nested class as suggested in cigien's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031520/2079303) is conventional and I recommend that approach. But it is not strictly necessary.

> However, in the code still does not compile

[Yes it does](https://godbolt.org/z/PWc1KM).

> saying that Container is a incomplete type.

This is not something that can be solved with a forward declaration. This means that you are using the **definition** of the class before that definition.

This is an error that is not produced in your example since the definition of `Container` is not used.

This error can be fixed by ordering the code differently such that the class is defined before its definition is used.